# QT5: Instantiate the same QML components multiple times

Tags: qml, qt5

I want to create component templates, meaning that I define my own MyButton type in a separate QML file, and I also want to define several singleton instances, like:

```
Predefined.qml:
pragma Singleton
[...]

property MyButton quitButton : quitButtonItem 
MyButton {
    id: quitButtonItem
    text: qsTr("Quit")
    imagesource : "qrc:/icons/quit.png"
}
```

then use it as:

```
Predefined { id: predefined }

Rectangle {
    predefined.quitButton {
        onClicked: console.log ("quit pressed.");
        anchors.bottom : parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter : parent.horizontalCenter
    }
}
```

a.) I don't want to use Loaders for this -> overkill
b.) Don't really want to define as my QML files as many components I want to
clone (eg QuitButton.qml, BackButtonQml, etc.)

Any idea how to have it done?
Thanks

Comment: Talking about nothing. Defining a custom component is the same action as you do in `Predefined.qml`. To instantiate the new item of this type you don't need `Loader`. Lack of understanding of the basics leads to errors of this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It can't be done.

The only way to instantiate an object declaratively from QML without a `Loader` is to create a new file for each component.

My suggestion for your usecase would simply be to create the files.
Alternatively, it appears you are doing some sort of navigation bar. What about unifying this in a single component?

I see two ways: have a single global nav bar for all your app, for example in `ApplicationWindow`'s `header`, or have a commonbase type like `YourPage.qml` where you implement your bar, and then simply inherit from it for your actual content.
Personally, I adopted the first solution.

Comment: Actually I created separate files for the different button types. This is not actually a toolbar, I simply want to make sure that throughout the application a "back" button is the very same back button (styling to the "extreme" sort of thing).